# Grub2, boot into existing OS option?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive

I've got Grub2 installed on a USB stick, and I want to add an entry to the `grub.cfg` that will boot in to another bootloader e.g. grub on the main harddrive.

Like how the Windows 7 install disk will skip starting its install if you press a key, or Arch Linux's "boot in to an existing OS" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use chainloading, altough you have to specify the boot record (ie. partition or drive) to boot to.

```
menuentry "Another bootloader" {
    set root=(hd1,0)
    chainloader +1
}
```

Should work for `(hd1)` too, if you want to use MBR. I hope you know how are the devices enumerated in GRUB, that's the only trouble here. If you want to test it first, you can enter `set root` and `chainloader` commands in GRUB command line, then type `boot`.

Comment: Ah yes I want to use it for the MBR, and hd1 works. Also adding MBR to my search terms (I hadn't thought of using that) for google also brings up solutions as well thanks.